# Rotate a quadric surface on $\mathbb{R}³$ so the crossed term doesn't appear

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Having the general quadric equation on three variables $$Ax²+By²+Cz²+2Dxy+2Eyz+2Fxz+2Gz+2Hy+2Iz+J$$,
I need to rotate a quadric surface $$11 x^2 + 9 y^2 + 12 z^2 + (2 \sqrt 3) xy - 72 = 0$$   using the method by eigenvalues, $det\left( \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  A&\frac{D}{2}\\
  \frac{D}{2}&B
\end{array}
\right]  + 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  -\lambda&0\\
  0&-\lambda
\end{array}
\right]\right) $,
but I don't know wich values should I take to fill the associated matrix.
I understand by now, if I want to eliminate the $xy$ term it is okay to use this method like it is used on $\mathbb{R}^2$, so If i needed to eliminate an $yz$ term, the values on the associated matrix should be coefficients of $y², z²$ and $yz$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're eliminating the $xy$ term, so you should use the coefficients of $x^2$, $xy$, $y^2$.

$$\begin{bmatrix} A & D/2 \\ D/2 & B \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 11 & \sqrt3 \\ \sqrt3 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$$

If you had several mixed terms, like $xy$, $yz$, then you would need to use a $3\times 3$ matrix, and find $3$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks, so, should I take the coefficient of $xy$ all complete (not caring about the 2)?

Comment: There are two different conventions, which you seem to be conflating. If the polynomial has $Ax^2+By^2+2Dxy$, then the matrix should have $[A,D;D,B]$. If the polynomial has $Ax^2+By^2+Dxy$, then the matrix should have $[A,D/2;D/2,B]$.

Comment: Thanks, I had no Idea on that!